# How to implement facebook-sdk to gatsby

Tags: facebook-sdk-4.0, gatsby, facebook-sdk-3.0

I'm trying to pull photos from a facebook page and place them on a my gatsby website, but I'm having trouble integrating Facebook SDK so I can use Graph API to grab the data I need. I've tried just getting the url of the photos and used them in img tags, but the photos disappear as I refresh the page.

I used axios to get the data

```
getFacebookAPI = () => {
let imgArray = []
  axios.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/me?fields=id,albums{photos{images}}&access_token=exampletoken')
      .then(response => {
          console.log(response)
          console.log(response.data.albums.data[0].photos.data)
          response.data.albums.data[0].photos.data.map(info => 
            imgArray.push(info.images[0].source)
          )
      })
  return imgArray.map(info => <img src={info} alt="facebook" />)
}
```